# Download manager caching downloads from JWPlayer

Tags: php, laravel-5, jwplayer, jwplayer7

My code

```
    <div id="my-video"></div>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/jwplayer.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("my-video").setup({
            autostart: false,
            file: "{{ asset('videos/18ThemeDetection.mp4') }}",
            image: "{{ asset('vimg/18ThemeDetection.png') }}",
            width: "1000",
            height: "700",
            primary: "html",
        });
    </script>
```

In this, my download manager is downloading the file.
How can I protect video from downloading?

Is it right what I am doing? or need to change something

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: First of all what browser are you using? Are you trying to stop your browser (or download manager) from downloading the file automatically? Or are you trying to prevent your users from downloading `videos/18ThemeDetection.mp4`?

Comment: If you answer to the last question is yes, you probably want to host your video with JWPlayer and use [URL signing](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/docs/developer-guide/delivery-api/url-token-signing/)